# compare multiple columns to multiple columns 2 sheets and return different columns if data matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have 2 Excel sheets. One with customer information, dispatch area and sales, and one with customer information and Geocoded information (long/lat) in columns. What I want to do it compare Sheet2's CustomerID, LocationID, CustomerName column's to Sheet1's columns of same name and if they match move over the data in the longitude, Lattitude columns from Sheet2 to the corresponding columns on Sheet1. I need all of the information complied for upload into a mapping system. I am not an Excel guru, starting more advanced classes next week, and I have been playing with vLookups, but never have been able to get it to work for this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayH3Y.jpg). Should I be using something else?

In the example below the first one should match and pull into Sheet1, the second one should not. We have about 7,000 records to parse.

Sheet1

CustomerID LocationID CustomerName Longitude Lattitude Sales$ Dispatch
1234        1          Smith                            125    DFW

4567        1          Jones                            450    DFW

Sheet2

CustomerID LocationID CustomerName Longitude Lattitude  Address  City

1234        1         Smith        25.xxx     -97.xxx  1234 Main Dallas

4567        2         Jones        25.xxx     -97.xxx  452 Comm  Buda

Comment: Is the Customer ID always unique?  You can't have two of the same Customer ID, correct?  Also, can you [edit] into your question your attempt at the `VLOOKUP` formula?  We can probably quickly fix it for you if we see how you were doing it yourself.

Comment: Use `Index` with `Match`

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated lookup and it will take a while to calculate 14K (lat and long for 7K) cells of data.

Per your supplied image, put this in Sheet1!D2 then drag right and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!D:D, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$9999)/((Sheet2!$A:$A=$A2)*(Sheet2!$B:$B=$B2)*(Sheet2!$C:$C=$C2)), 1)), "")
```

You could also try a SUMIFS. This will only work if the three value combinations are unique in Sheet2 so a COUNIFS may be necessary but it would be faster without it.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A, $A2, Sheet2!$B:$B, $B2, Sheet2!$C:$C, $C2)=1, SUMIFS(Sheet2!D:D, Sheet2!$A:$A, $A2, Sheet2!$B:$B, $B2, Sheet2!$C:$C, $C2), "")
```